# How to count without a counter in a select?

Tags: c#, foreach

Sometimes, during development phase, I need to see if e.g. a name is changed for each element created or just wish to differentiate between different instances' names in an array. That behavior is strictly for development-stage and only to be applied during a short period of time (hence no need to long term solution - Q&D is just fine).

Usually, I introduce a counter in the following way but it just stroke me that there might be a better way. Basically, I wish to emulate behavior of the counter variable of *for* without actually introducing it (staying at *foreach*).

```
int counter = 1;
IEnumerable<Typo> result = originals.Select(original 
  => new Thingy { Name = "Hazaa" + counter++ });
```

Comment: Use the overload of [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) that includes the index.

Comment: Did you look at [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. The title talks about `foreach` but there is no `foreach` in your code.

Comment: @loli: There are a couple of problems with that. First, you are going to have to search the list for *every single item* in the loop. So it's now O(n^2). Second, if there are duplicate items, it won't work, because you'll only get the index of the first match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) overload of `Select`

```
IEnumerable<Typo> result = originals.Select((original, counter)
  => new Thingy { Name = "Hazaa" + (counter + 1) });
```

Comment: Well, there should be some kind of intellisense for this... Exactly what I was looking for. +1 for rightonspotness but also brevity.